# How to prevent SQL multiple-join-rows error and apply values for multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-update, netezza, multiple-join-rows

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Update canceled: attempt to update a target row
>   with values from multiple join rows

Is there a way to avoid this error and update each row that contains E, despite having multiple join rows?

```
UPDATE V
SET 
V.S = M.S,
V.T = M.T,
V.U = M.U
FROM MAP M
WHERE AND V.E = M.E;
```

Comment: One alternative would be use a function like MIN or MAX, according to your logic.

Comment: Another method is to use ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by .... order by .... )    This is assuming you know which of the multiple record rows you want to select.   Then just update where ROW_NUMBER() = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch one value per `E`.  I would be tempted to use `row_number()`:

```
UPDATE V
    SET V.S = M.S,
        V.T = M.T,
        V.U = M.U
    FROM (SELECT M.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E ORDER BY E) as seqnum
          FROM MAP M
         ) M
    WHERE V.E = M.E AND seqnum = 1;
```

However, you may have other logic for selecting the particular values from `MAP` that you want to use for the update.